# Global Parameter set using Open API configurations?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, springdoc

I am using `Spring Boot REST OpenAPI 3` specification. In this example, I am looking to globally set the headers (`Custom-Header-Version=v1`) which I want to pass while making a request to each endpoint(s).

Now issue is that I've **100 of REST endpoint** and for each endpoint I need to keep adding `@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.HEADER .....`, this configuration, instead I was looking to set it globally. Is there any way if we can do it in OpenAPI?

Is there any way to remove SmartBear logo from Spring doc ui ?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Tag(name = "contact", description = "the Contact API")
public class HelloController {

    @Operation(summary = "Find Contacts by name", description = "Name search by %name% format", tags = {"contact"})
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "successful operation", content = @Content(array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = PersonDTO.class))))})
    @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.HEADER, description = "Custom Header To be Pass", name = "Accept-version"
            , content = @Content(schema = @Schema(type = "string", defaultValue = "v1", allowableValues = {"v1"}, implementation = PersonDTO.class)))
    @GetMapping(value = "/contacts", headers = {"Custom-Header-Version=v1"})
    public ResponseEntity<List<PersonDTO>> findAll(
            @Parameter(description = "Page number, default is 1") @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "1") int pageNumber,
            @Parameter(description = "Name of the contact for search.") @RequestParam(required = false) String name) {

            return null;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try the following code. Added .example("v1") in the code mentioned above by `ouled saber`

```
@Component
public class GlobalHeaderOperationCustomizer implements OperationCustomizer {
    @Override
    public Operation customize(Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {

        Parameter customHeaderVersion = new Parameter().in(ParameterIn.HEADER.toString()).name("Custom-Header-Version")
                .description("Custom Header Version)").schema(new StringSchema()).example("v1").required(false);

        operation.addParametersItem(customHeaderVersion);       
        return operation;
    }
```

I have same requirement and on swagger I am getting like below

[Image from swagger ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNiPW.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can just define a OperationCustomizer.

```
@Component
public class GlobalHeaderOperationCustomizer implements OperationCustomizer {
    @Override
    public Operation customize(Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
        Parameter parameterHeader = new Parameter()
                .in(ParameterIn.HEADER.toString())
                .schema(new StringSchema().addEnumItem("v1")._default("v1").name("Accept-version"))
                .description("Custom Header To be Pass");;
        operation.addParametersItem(parameterHeader);
        return operation;
    }
}
```

Comment: With this code I dont see default value is working correctly, its taking no default value.

Comment: Could you please reply to above comment?

Comment: Could you please reply here as its pending since so long ?

Comment: This does indeed work if you only have one OpenAPi config (~ one old springfox 'Docket') and are doing the config through `springdoc.packagesToScan` and `springdoc.pathsToMatch` spring properties.

If you have a config with multiple `GroupedOpenApi`, then you need to add the  customizer to each GroupedOpenApi through 

`GroupedOpenApi.builder().packagesToScan(...).addOpenApiCustomiser(globalHeaderCustomizer()).build();`