# Spring boot reusable springdoc-openapi parameter annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I have few controller classes that all requires a header param. To document swagger I am adding this `@Parameter` annotation to all my endpoints:

```java
    @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.HEADER, description = "some description", name = "some name", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(allowableValues = {VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, VALUE4})))
    @GetMapping
    public void method(@RequestHeader .....) {
    //some code here
    }
```

Problem is I don't like the idea of repeating the same annotation all over the controller methods. Is there a nice clean solution to have a reusable annotation here?

Answer (score 2):

So partial fix is create my own custom interface like that:

```
@Target({PARAMETER, METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.HEADER, description = "some description", name = "some name", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(allowableValues = {VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, VALUE4})))
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation {
}
```

that way I can reuse that and save some code. Problem is when some values differ. For example if allowableValues differ between endpoints I can't reuse that one. I can't figure out how can I pass some arguments to my custom annotation to override the default values...

Comment: You can try this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60559044/3493829